# Unresolved symbols when linking a program using libcurl in Qt

Tags: qt, curl

I'm using Qtcreator

When I try to compile my solution I keep getting this error(This is from my Qtcreator):

```
main.obj:-1: error: LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__curl_easy_strerror referenced in function _main
main.obj:-1: error: LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__curl_easy_strerror referenced in function _main
main.obj:-1: error: LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__curl_easy_perform referenced in function _main
main.obj:-1: error: LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__curl_easy_perform referenced in function _main
main.obj:-1: error: LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__curl_easy_perform referenced in function _main
debug\test.exe:-1: error: LNK1120: 5 unresolved externals
```

Source (This is a sample.c from their page [curl](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/example.html)http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/example.html):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <curl/curl.h>

int main(void)
{
  CURL *curl;
  CURLcode res;

  curl = curl_easy_init();
  if(curl) {
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "http://example.com");
    /* example.com is redirected, so we tell libcurl to follow redirection */
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1L);

    /* Perform the request, res will get the return code */
    res = curl_easy_perform(curl);
    /* Check for errors */
    if(res != CURLE_OK)
      fprintf(stderr, "curl_easy_perform() failed: %s\n",
              curl_easy_strerror(res));

     /* always cleanup */
    curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
    }
  return 0;
  }
```

I added this to my .pro file

```
INCLUDEPATH = C:\Users\Uporabnik\Desktop\curl-7.38.0\curl-7.38.0\include
```

Comment: You are probably missing `LIBS +=` from your .pro file. Please add your .pro to the question, as well as path to libcurl stuff and the compile command that fails.

Answer (score 0):

You need something like this in your .pro file:

```
LIBS += -lcurl -LC:/Users/Uporabnik/Desktop/curl-7.38.0/curl-7.38.0
```

`-l` tells that library with this name should be used, and `-L` tells that this dir should be used when searching for libs (in addition to other dirs already searched). In *qmake*, this will also do the right thing even with MSVC toolchain, I believe, and not only Mingw *gcc*.

Note, the exact path and lib name are a bit of a guess in my part, you may need to adjust them.

Comment: Now i get this error:-1: error: LNK1104: cannot open file 'curl.lib'

Comment: Where do you have `curl.lib` file, in your disk?

Comment: I don't have a curl.lib file. I downloaded .zip file from http://curl.haxx.se/download.html and inside isn't .lib file. - curl-7.38.0

Comment: @Seba well then, the obvious question is, which zip? If you downloaded sources, you will need to build them to get the library you can use in your own programs. If you downloaded just *curl* binary, it probably can't be used in your own programs as a library (it will lack the .lib file required for linking). If you downloaded pre-build development libs (which you apparently didn't, if you don't have a .lib file), then they would have to match the compiler you use yourself.

Comment: I downloaded this file:  curl-7.38.0.zip. It is 3th link from the top of the page.

Comment: Well, then read the `docs/INSTALL`, find the section for your OS and compiler. Or check out the pre-built binaries (looking at that download page, package type *devel* or *libcurl*, not sure which without looking what's in them).

Comment: As a general note, in order to link your program against libcurl in windows, you will need a .lib file (only during link phase of building your own application) and a .dll file (during both linking and when running, then usually copied to same directory where your .exe is).

Comment: So that means i have to build a .lib file somehow from my  curl-7.38.0.zip directory ?